# How to show errors in Python code with VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to configure VSCode in such a way that I can see red squiggly lines when there is an error in my python code.

My VSCode currently shows me Python syntax errors (e.g. `pri nt("hello")` will have a red squiggly line), but not the following errors:

```
class Dog:
    attr1 = "mammal"
    attr2 = "dog"

    def fun(self):
        print("I'm a", self.attr1)
        print("I'm a", self.attr3)


Rodger = Dog()

print(Rodger.attr1)
Rodger.bark()
```

In the code above I would like to see a red squiggly line on `print("I'm a", self.attr3)` since this object doesn't have a `self.attr3` attribute, and `Rodger.bark()` since this object doesn't have a `bark` method.

Comment: I've posted the answer, please if you find it usefull mark it as answered. Also if the answer isn't clear please tell me so that I can explain that part.

Answer (score 2):

You will need linters like Pylint which is supported by vscode.
From the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting):

> linting detects use of an uninitialized or undefined variable, calls
> to undefined functions, missing parentheses, and even more subtle
> issues such as attempting to redefine built-in types or functions.

After that you will need to turn on strict mode. Here is the [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) on how to do that. Microsoft explains it better than I can do on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add python env path to your vscode.

- Press ⌘ + ⇧ + P on the keyboard.
  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDgUn.png)
- And then choose your python interpreter path.
  (VS code will display available python interpreters.)
  Then, vscode will detect the attributes itself.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: nah it's already set for me